# Installing zoph on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux. I tried to install `zoph` by using `apt-get install zoph`. But this shows the error:

```
E:unable to locate package zoph.
```

I have seen methods to install `zoph` on Ubuntu 12.04 version but not on 14.04.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance: Reputation 8 user already!  **;-)**

Comment: https://github.com/jeroenrnl/zoph/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoph is in beta and only available in [source code](https://github.com/jeroenrnl/zoph/releases), so not through the standard Ubuntu Software center.

So you have two possibilities:

1. If you know what source code, compiling and linking is, [build it from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564801/how-to-build-a-source-package)
2. If you're not very technical: wait until version 1.0 has been released. (**No, really!** If you've never programmed before: forget about 1. above)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Zoph is written in PHP and therefore does not require compilation. You can install Apache, PHP and MySQL using apt-get and then simply place Zoph's files in Apache's webroot.